# VS is telling my my class doesn't exist when it totally does

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I've written a MarkupExtension for my WPF application. The XAML designer in Visual Studio 2012 reports the following error.

> Error 1   The name "MyMarkupExtension" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyNamespace".

It does exist in that namespace. I've triple checked it. I've Built, Rebuilt, Cleaned and Built and shut down and restarted visual studio. Nothing works. I don't understand. Its in the same blasted assembly. I'm not doing any funny tricks. There is no reason this should not work except that Visual Studio secretly hates me!

Comment: I'm not sure it's a secret ;)  Is it in the same assembly as your XAML?

Comment: Have you tried removing the namespace from the class "MyMarkupExtension"?  Sometimes I get a collision between the default namespace for my project and the namespace for a class, even when the two match.  Sometimes removing the namespace helps.

Comment: @kenny Yes. Same assembly.

Comment: Not seeing the XAML and class def... just guessing that the class isn't public/internal?

Comment: Please post the XAML (Window declaration and use of the markup extension) and the class declaration for the markup extension (including class attributes and interface declarations).

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the XAML. Its an intermittent problem. I fixed it by compiling as "x86" and than switching back to "Any CPU". Now everything works. I've had this issue before; don't remember how I solved it.

Comment: IT's BACK. I am so sick of this!! This is killing time! I can't move forward because I can't compile! I'm am tempted of changing my code back to Visual Studio 2010! Both Visual Studio and Blend are telling me objects don't exist. This is happening on code that wasn't changed and worked just an hour ago. Blend and Visual Studio 2012 are broken! Microsoft Connect ignores people with obscure problems so don't recommend that please! Please is anyone having or has had a similar problem? I can't list my XAML because its thousands of lines.

Comment: I had this problem just one hour ago. I put the extension into another namespace, used it without problems, then put it back into the original namespace and the problem was gone. Seems to be some kind of caching problem of the designer.